# Remote to Local rolling backup script

Tags: linux, bash, debian, backup, tar

I'm trying to create a bash script that runs through crontab to execute a backup remote to local. Everything works but my rolling backup part, where it only keeps 4 backups.

```
#!/bin/bash
dateForm=`date +%m-%d-%Y`
fileName=[redacted]-"$dateForm"
echo backup started for [redacted] on: $dateForm >> /home/backups/backLog.log
ls -tQ /home/backups/[redacted] | tail -n+5 | xargs -r rm

ssh root@[redacted] "tar jcf - -C /home/[redacted]/[redacted] ." > "/home/backups/[redacted]/$fileName".tar.bz2

if [ ! -f "/home/backups/[redacted]/$fileName.tar.bz2" ]
then
   echo "something went wrong with the backup for $fileName!" >> /home/backups/backLog.log
else
        echo "Backup completed for $fileName" >> /home/backups/backLog.log
    fi
```

the ls line will work if executed in the directory just fine, but because crontab is executing it and I need the script to be outside of the folder it's targeting. I can't get it to target the rm to the correct directory utilizing the piped ls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with an interesting solution after studying the man page for ls a little more and utilizing find to grab the full paths.

```
ls -tQ $(find /home/backups/[redacted] -type f -name "*") | tail -n+5 | xargs -r rm
```

just posting an answer for someone that didn't want to create a rolling backup script that completely depended on date formatting, as there would ALWAYS be at least 4 backups in the folder targeted.